# Update Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create an update form.  When I send the form it shows me that the variable person has not been defined.  It's important to say that this variable contains the information obtained in the first query that is used to fill out the first table.

So far everything works well.  However, when the user presses the button modify, a message saying that the variable person has not been defined.  When i try to re-use the variable serial in the last query it tells me that isn't defined either.  I don't really know why if i did at the beginning of the script.

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CTE Modificar Registro</title>
<?php
include "conexiondblocal.php";
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
$serial = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['numeroorden']); 
$qry= "SELECT * FROM producto  WHERE numeroorden = $serial";
$muestra = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
$person=$muestra->fetch_array();
}
?>
<style type="text/css">
#cuerpo form table {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<link href="../CTE/estilospaginas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cuerpo">
<script>
   $( "#entregaacliente,#fecharecepcion").datepicker();

  </script>

 <div id="formulario">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">


      <div> <label for="inputproducto">Producto</label>  <input name="inputproducto"type="text" class="tabla" id="producto" value = "<?php echo $person['producto']; ?>" /> 
    </div>


            <div> <label for="inputproducto">Orden número</label>  <input name="inputcedula"type="text" class="tabla" id="inputcedula" value = "<?php echo $person['cedula']; ?>" /> 
    </div>


           <div> <label for="inputtipodeservicio">Cedula</label>  <input name="inputtipodeservicio"type="text" id="inputtipodeservicio" value = "<?php echo $person['tipodeservicio']; ?>" /> 
    </div>



         <div> <label for="inputnumeromarca">Numero de Marca</label>  <input name="inputnumeromarca"type="text" id="inputnumeromarca" value = "<?php echo $person['numeromarca']; ?>" /> 
    </div>

          <div> <label for="inputmarca">Marca</label>  <input name="inputmarca"type="text" id="inputmarca" value = "<?php echo $person['marca']; ?>" /> 
    </div>    


    <div> <label for="inputtelefono">Modelo</label>  <input name="inputmodelo"type="text" id="inputmodelo" value = "<?php echo $person['modelo']; ?>" /> </div>  

    <div> <label for="inputproducto">Almacen</label>  <input name="inputalmacen"type="text" id="inputalmacen" value = "<?php echo $person['almacen']; ?>" /> </div>


          <div> <label for="inputmarca">Dano</label>  <input name="inputdano"type="text" id="inputdano" value = "<?php echo $person['dano']; ?>" /> </div>  



       <div> <label for="inputfecharecepcion">Fecha de Recepción</label>  <input name="inputfecharecepcion"type="text" id="inputfecharecepcion" value = "<?php echo $person['fecharecepcion']; ?>" /> 
    </div>     


         <div> <label for="inputfecharecepcion">Técnico</label>
          <textarea name="inputtecnico" cols="30" id="inputtecnico"  /><?php echo $person['tecnico']; ?>
    </textarea> </div>

    <div> <label for="inputestado">Estado</label>  <select name="inputestado"type="text"value = "<?php echo $person['estado']; ?>" id="inputestado"> <option>Reparado </option>
            <option>Pendiente </option>
            <option>Entregado</option>
          </select> </div>

  <div> <label for="inputsede">Sede</label>  <select name="inputsede"value = "<?php echo $person['sede']; ?>"type="text" id="inputsede"> <option>Centro </option>
            <option>Calipso </option>
          </select>  </div>


        <div> <label for="inputentregaacliente">Entrega a Cliente</label>  <input name="inputentregaacliente"type="text" id="inputentregaacliente" value = "<?php echo $person['entregaacliente']; ?>" /> </div> 


        <div id="enviarboton">

        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value= "Modificar"/>

        </div>

 <input type="hidden" name="numeroorden" value="<?php echo $serial;?>"/> 

</form>

</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$producto= 
"UPDATE producto 
 SET producto = '$_POST[inputproducto]',
       cedula = '$_POST[inputcedula]',
       tipodeservicio = '$_POST[inputtipodeservicio]',
       numeromarca = '$_POST[inputnumeromarca]',
       marca = '$_POST[inputmarca]',
       modelo = '$_POST[inputmodelo]',
       almacen = '$_POST[inputalmacen]',
       dano = '$_POST[inputdano]',
       fecharecepcion = '$_POST[inputfecharecepcion]',
       tecnico = '$_POST[inputtecnico]',
       estado = '$_POST[inputestado]',
       sede = '$_POST[inputsede]',
       entregaacliente = '$_POST[inputentregaacliente]',
     numeroorden = '$_POST[numeroorden]'
 WHERE numeroorden = $serial";

mysqli_query($con,$producto);

echo "El usuario ha sido modificado";

} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're setting `$person` inside an if statement. if `$_POST['submit']` is not set (on the first time through), `$person is being set. On form submission, `$_POST['submit']` is set, and that code is not run.

Comment: And your code is prone to mysql injection, remember, never trust user input.